# java web app using axis2 on oracle weblogic server error

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, apache-axis

I have a java web application using axis2 stub to call a .net webservice that receieves a string parameter. When I run the web application using tomcat server, it works fine.

But when I use Oracle weblogic server I get the following error :

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: 
First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
```

What could be the cause to get this error? Please help me. I really need to fix this but I can't.

Comment: If it works in Tomcat my guess is some kind of classloading issue. Weblogic might load a different set of classes than Tomcat. You could try and to add a Weblogic.xml file to your WEB-INF folder, and in Weblogic..xml specify the classloader delegation.

Comment: See here for info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html you're looking true prefer-web-inf-classes tag

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps @ http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html for deploying axis2 onto weblogic